# Change index.html into start.html

Tags: html, .htaccess

Please I hope somebody can help me because i've been dealing with this problem already for about 2 weeks and I just can't figure out how to fix it.

I have added a new part to my website since I'm offering a totally new service. I put the new part under `index2.html`.

I have a new start/default page called `start.html`, on here they can choose to click on the service they are coming for, so will be either going to the old website part which is under `index.html` or they will go to the new part which is under `index2.html`.

To have people go directly to `start.html` I have put `DirectoryIndex start.html` in my htaccess file and this works fine. But when they choose which website part they want to go to and click on it they don't get the website `index.html` or `index2.html` but they get a message in the screen that their connection is not private and you will see a red `https` in front of the url link. I don't want it to be https, it just needs to be http.

Individually all the links work fine. So I don't understand why the message appears and what can I do about it?

I also did a link check on W3C, it said:

> error Line: 87 www.example.com/index2.html
>   Status: 500 Can't connect to www.example.com:443
>   This is a server side problem. Check the URI.
>
> error Line: 78 `https://www.example.com/index.html`
>   Status: 500 Can't connect to www.example.com:443
>   This is a server side problem. Check the URI.

Comment: The behaviour you've stated suggests you have links/resources pointing to HTTPS URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `index.html` as the default file for `/folder/`,

*ie. pointing the browser to `/folder/` takes you to `/folder/index.html`*

is such a widespread convention, you are almost definitely better off not messing with it.

My suggestion would be:

1. Rename `/index.html` to `/old-part/index.html`
2. Rename `/index2.html` to `/new-part/index.html`
3. Rename `/start.html` to `/index.html`

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice, I guess I will go do that later on today then! But I am just afraid I will lose my top position in google and have some dead links when I do this. Won''t I?

Comment: Google respects 301 Redirects so you can be reasonably confident that even if you lose a position temporarily - and that might not even happen - you will regain the position as soon as Google has figured out what you've done. Google is unlikely to want to punish a webmaster for changing the URI of a page containing useful content, but you do have to write the 301 Redirects clearly in your `.htaccess` file. Also, once you write the 301 Redirects into your `.htaccess`, you won't have any dead links.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you adviced and it all works great again! Am I wrong for thinking that I actually don't need to do any 301 redirects? Because the index.html page still excists, it only has different content because it has the content from the start.html page now, but that's actually good. And I did change all the index.html links in my navlist into old-part/index.html so all the links are going well I guess. Or would it still be necessary to do the 301 redirects anyway? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Given what you have described above, it sounds like you probably wouldn't need to do any 301 redirects after all. From now on the search engines will be able to find all of your content. I'm delighted to hear that everything is working for you now. Also, did you mean to award dreamweaver's supportive answer as the "Best Answer"?

Comment: Ok nice then I'm done, great! Oh no definitly not, I'm new to stack overflow, don't know how it exactly works, let me check again.Thanks for your good help Rounin!

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Rounin.  A browser/website is designed to look for a file called index.html, index.php, index.xhtml, and so forth for the main page of the site depending on the type of website it is when it comes to your domain.

You need to do what Rounin suggested for your files to maintain a proper website without any headaches.